# httpChannel.setRequestHeader with httpChannel.redirectTo

Tags: redirect, http-headers, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, request-headers

I'm having trouble with my Firefox-Addon.

With my extension, I'd like to redirect requests that match a certain pattern. So far, **the redirection is working fine** with

> httpChannel.redirectTo()

**Now I'd like to add / modify the request headers for the redirection** (as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers )

My code so far:

```
console.log("start");
const {Cu,Ci} = require('chrome');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var httpRequestObserver =
{
    observe: function(subject, topic, data)
    {
        var httpChannel, requestURL;
        if (topic == "http-on-modify-request") {
            httpChannel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            requestURL = httpChannel.URI.spec;
            if (requestURL.indexOf('www.3und80.de') > -1) {

                    console.log("match url");           
                    newURL = 'http://www.genialschenken.de/';

/*This has no effect*/
httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);

                    console.log("redirecting...");
                    httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI(newURL, null, null));
            }
        return;
        }
    }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(httpRequestObserver, "http-on-modify-request", false);
```

Sadly, the line

> httpChannel.setRequestHeader("X-Hello", "World", false);

has no effect.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try moving the setReuqestHeader line to after the redirectTo line. Let me know how that works

Comment: Ok this is an option: You detect if it's a redirect, by checking httpChannel.statusCode or something and if it is then you abort the request and then copy all parameters and create a new request with proper referer etc, this will work for sure.

Comment: Try also asking other places like [mozillaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=19), and [ask.m.o](https://ask.mozilla.org/) and of course there's irc but you have to be on all day [#extdev](https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%23extdev)

Answer (score 0):

From IRC:

> 00:58 Fallen  noida: nsIChannelEventSink
>
> 00:58 Fallen  and nsIInterfaceRequestor
>
> 00:59   Fallen  I didn't read the link though
>
> 01:00   Fallen  noida: http://mxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/calendar/providers/caldav/calDavCalendar.js#2828

@3und80 Let's research this more and develop an solution here.